# Persist an Object throughout the application using Spring framwork

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring framework for my web application where I have to persist the information of object, say, - Account. The scenario as below:

1. User can select an account from dropdown list of his all accounts and he can view + Add + Modified the data of that selected account throughout the application.
2. If user change the account - A to account - B, he can view all the information of only B account where he can perform same operations.
3. Once user logged out and logged in again, he can see the information of latest selected account.

Is there any way I can get the selected account object reference over the Controller/DAO level apart from storing information in session?

Comment: I would suggest you do not try to be "efficient" to start off. Unless you have an accurate picture of the hardware and software architecture the decisions made might be counter productive.

Comment: Thanks BevynQ, I have updated my question, I am looking for get selected record in context which i can use to query and get results

Answer (score 1):

You have only 4 ways of keeping an information throughout a *discussion* between a client and a server :

- in the session
- in (possibly hidden) fields of a form
- in the url
- in a cookie

if the information is *sensible*, you should keep it in session because it cannot be read nor altered by the client side. For the 3 other way, you must assume the value could be forged, so you should digitally sign it if you want to be sure it was not altered.